# Square root with javascript returns ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, pow, sqrt, referenceerror

I'm trying to get the square root of a number using javascript.
To do that, I tried the following codes:

```js
<script>
var rad = sqrt(4);
alert(rad);
</script>
```

(this returns in Firefox's console "ReferenceError: sqrt is not defined")

```js
<script>
var rad = pow(4,0.5);
alert(rad);
</script>
```

(but I get "ReferenceError: pow is not defined")

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that error is reasonable, since you're calling it as a separate function. Prefix them with `Math.`
as those methods exist in `Math` object

```
var rad = Math.sqrt(4);
alert(rad);
```

Another way is to create a separate function but I would not advise the use of this, but anyway, here it is

```
function sqrt(n){
  return Math.sqrt(n);
}
var rad = sqrt(4);
alert(rad);
```